# AFD managed certificates - should they have auto-rotated by now

Tags: azure-front-door

Some of our AFD managed certificates have an expiry warning next to them saying they will expire in 24 days.

Clicking the warning opens a pop-up that says AFD managed certificates will auto-rotate 90 days ahead of expiry.

So I wonder if anyone knows if I have a problem, whether the warning is referring to something else, or if any day soon they will auto-rotate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the Azure Front Door managed certificate option, the certificates are managed and auto-rotates within 90 days of expiry time by Azure Front Door. For the Azure Front Door Standard/Premium managed certificate option, the certificates are managed and auto-rotates within 45 days of expiry time by Azure Front Door. If you're using an Azure Front Door managed certificate and see that the certificate expiry date is less than 60 days away or 30 days for the Standard/Premium SKU, file a support ticket.